# Eclipse JVM Version won't change

Tags: jvm, version, mismatch

I need to get my eclipse install to use 1.7 update 51.  I've installed both JRE and JDK's matching this version for 64 and 32 bit.  If I change the vm in eclipse.ini I get an error code 1 saying eclipse cannot be started.  If I change the compliance level in window -> preferences then it says that it's changed but after writing a simple application and running it in eclipse using RuntimeMXBean I'm being told 24.51-b03 is being used.  I would assume this means update 51 is in use but my workspace is still complaining about major/minor version mismatches.

Any help/insight is appreciated

edit:
Here is the output of

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        String jvmArgs = runtimeMXBean.getVmVersion();
        System.out.println(runtimeMXBean.getSpecVersion() + " " + runtimeMXBean.getVmVersion());
    }
```

1.7 24.51-b03

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, kinda. I built my jar with 1.7 update 51 and was using in a project with 1.7 update 51. No idea why it wasn't working, I just downgraded to 1.6 on the jar I built and it works.